# order in $\mathbb{F}_5^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I have a confusion with the following problem.

Let $\alpha$ a root of $f(x)=x^2-x+2\in\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_5{(\alpha)}$. Compute the order of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}^*$.

My attempt.

If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then

\begin{align*}
\alpha^2-\alpha+2&=0\\
\alpha^2-\alpha&=-2\\
\alpha(\alpha-1)&=3
\end{align*}

but there's no $\alpha$ that satisfies this (so I don't have a clear conclussion).

What I'm missing? or I'm doing this in a wrong way?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "there's no $\alpha$ that satisfies this", keep in mind that you're working in $\Bbb F_5(\alpha)$, which is a field specifically constructed to make $\alpha$ a root of that polynomial. So there *is* an $\alpha$ that satisfies that, namely $\alpha$!

It's a bit hard to say what $\alpha$ "looks like", since it isn't an element of $\Bbb F_5$. It's a symbol that lives in a world outside $\Bbb F_5$ and is a root of $f(x)$ in that world. (Compare to defining $i$ as a root of $x^2+1$ over the reals, giving us $\Bbb C = \Bbb R(i)$. It's hard to say what $i$ "looks like" from within the reals.)

Given that $\alpha^2 - \alpha + 2 = 0$, it follows that $\alpha^2 = \alpha - 2$. Use this to simplify the progressive powers of $\alpha$:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha^2 &= &\alpha -2\\
\alpha^3 &= &\alpha(\alpha-2)\\
&= &\alpha^2 - 2\alpha\\
&= &(\alpha-2) - 2\alpha\\
&= &-\alpha - 2\\
\alpha^4 &= &\alpha(-\alpha-2)\\
&= &\ldots
\end{align}$$

Keep on going until you get $\alpha^n = 1$ for some $n > 1$.

Comment: Now it's clear ! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Nico I should have mentioned: we know that the order of $\alpha$ divides $24$ (because $\lvert \Bbb F_5^*\rvert = 5^2-1=24$). So you only need to check $\alpha^d$ where $d\mid n$. This will save you from going through the entire list of powers. For example, you can skip $\alpha^5$ and go directly to $\alpha^6 = (\alpha^3)^2 = (-\alpha-2)^2 = \ldots$, simplifying as before with the aid of $\alpha^2=\alpha-2$. Next do $\alpha^8 = (\alpha^4)^2$, etc.

Comment: Actually I know that fact, but yesterday I didn't notice the importance in this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @Nico You're welcome!